# Why the kernel doesn't update automatically?

Tags: apt, kernel

I have two servers running 12.04 LTS. #1 has upgraded to kernel 3.2.0-57. #2 is stuck on 3.2.0-34. #2 is getting all other package upgrades. BUT, the kernel is never upgraded. This is what I have researched:

1. `/etc/apt/sources.list` are identical on both servers.
2. The repository caches are identical, verified by: apt-cache search , and: dpkg -L linux-image.

I have done: `sudo apt-get update` on the faulty server.
I have done: `sudo apt-get upgrade` on the faulty server.

I have verified that the kernel is not "pinned" by the following:

```
apt-mark unhold linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic
```

The system replied:

```
linux-image-3.2.0-generic was already not hold
```

Why don't this system upgrade the kernel when it gets other packages without a problem? Aptitude is apparently working as other packages seem to update. The cache and source list are the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why don't this system upgrade the kernel when it gets other packages without a problem?

Most likely because you (or somebody) removed the `linux-generic` metapackage. For the kernel update automatically this package is indispensable:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Now you will have automatic Kernel updates.

Comment: That did it! What could I have studied, or looked at in order to have known this important piece of information? I was basically looking at repository settings and repository cache. Of course, I am immensely gratified for your help. How this got deleted is a mystery. Something happened when /boot partition filled up on a kernel upgrade, and the system failed to boot to the new image. I had to grub back to a download image and clean up some old images. Possibly that is where it got deleted. I was careful to delete these images in groups, like abi, config, initrd, system and vmlinuz.

Comment: Check this `apt-cache rdepends linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic` Then look for a package with the same name but without version.

Comment: Trying this same fix today, I needed to install `linux-image-generic-lts-trusty` instead (for 12.04) - presumably that's a change since 14.04 was released.

Comment: @DanParsonson that's the [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), and that doesn't assure you your kernel will be automatically upgraded to the latest kernel for your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Braiam - indeed, but installing `linux-image-generic` did not fix the auto-updating problem I had(/have), installing `linux-image-generic-lts-trusty` also installed the latest kernel, and running `apt-cache rdepends` on the kernel of another 12.04 box that's auto-updating successfully listed `linux-image-generic-lts-trusty` but not `linux-image-generic`. However there hasn't been a new kernel released since my latest attempt at fixing the problem so it may indeed still not be auto-updating - in which case I'm stumped.

Comment: Well, as you say, installing `linux-image-generic-lts-trusty` hasn't resolved the auto-update problem, sorry about that - back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: @DanParsonson I recommend you to report a bug against the linux-kernel package so linux-generic actually depends on the latest lts kernel