# unattended-upgrades stopped updating on Dec 17 2020

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades

I have a number of servers running Ubuntu 18.04, all of which stopped updating anything on Dec 17.  No errors seen in the unattended-upgrades or unattended-upgrades-dpkg log files.

If I do apt-get update I see some stuff download, but if I do apt-get upgrade nothing upgrades.  This is despite running old kernels that have had recent vulnerabilties for which there are upgrades.

Anyone know the best way to troubleshoot why this is (or isn't!) happening?

Mirror in use is `archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/390939/why-the-kernel-doesnt-update-automatically This is the correct answer. Needed linux-generic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No updates since a long time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304240/no-updates-since-a-long-time)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is wrong with your systems, at least that is causing this.

**Updates have resumed as of 1/4/21. If you do not receive any updates in the next day or so, please report back.**

**There haven't been any updates since then** to the 18.04 repositories.  I suspect they're taking the last two weeks of the year off.  I got a `google-chrome-unstable` update on the 18th, but that is from a PPA.

The "stuff downloaded" is the index files that your systems use to determine if there have been updates or not.

[image]

Source: [Ubuntu Updates](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_logs?commit=Filter&head_only=true&noppa=1&vals=bionic&type=dists&levels%5Bsecurity%5D=1&levels%5Bupdates%5D=1&levels%5Bbase%5D=1)

Answer (score -1):

> if I do apt-get upgrade nothing upgrades.

This is the wrong command.

Do 'apt full-upgrade' and then reboot all of the affected servers. I additionally recommend 'apt clean' afterwards to empty the package cache, 'apt autoremove' to get rid of any obsoleted packages, and 'apt purge' to remove any lingering configurations.

Comment: Surely `sudo apt full-upgrade`; weird they used apt-get, as apt has been canonical since 16.04. Sounds like full-upgrade is exactly equivalent to dist-upgrade, so I'm a little behind the times too.

Comment: @pbhj Well, they didn't specify `sudo` so I followed suit. TBH I often do a `sudo -s` before administrative tasks myself. I think there are some subtle differences between `apt-get dist-upgrade` and `apt full-upgrade` but nothing that is normally important and I favour the one with less typing.

Comment: FWIW I did look and received wisdom is that dist-upgrade and full-upgrade are identical, the latter being a new name as the former was apparently confusing.